# Insert bulk product into woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to insert many product in woocommerce at once time? The product in excel not CSV. around 1000++ products there.

Any plugin that I can do use it?

Thanks

Comment: Just export it to CSV from excel?

Comment: how to export from excel to csv?

Comment: Google "excel save csv" First result, [Microsofts own step by step guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx#BMexport).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export as a CSV file, then use this plugin to import: http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/

There's also a paid option: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-csv-import-suite/

Answer (score 0):

Export as a CSV , then you have the simplest plugin to import simple product with images into WooCommerce [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/product-import-export-for-woo)

If you have other types of product in your CSV other than simple product they have a premium version to handle these things [here](http://www.xadapter.com/product/product-import-export-plugin-for-woocommerce/)